# Update a table of cells with information added from modal

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to update my table of cells with information added from a modal. It needs to update the table by placing the name entered from the modal into the grid, how would I go about doing this?

This is my modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1>Reservation</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                
                <input type="text" name="field1" placeholder="Name" id="name">

                <input type="text" name="field2" placeholder="Email" id="email">

                <input type="text" name="field3" placeholder="PhoneNumber" id="phonenumber">
                
                

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

                <input class="btn submit" value="Submit">
                <input class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Close">

      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is the javascript I have to include an eventListener to trigger when a user clicks on a grid.

```
<script>

var cells = document.querySelectorAll('td');
cells.forEach((e)=>{
e.addEventListener("click", ()=>{

    $('.modal').modal("show");

    })
})
```

I declare the table as follows:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <table>
      <tr>
         <td>Table Cell</td>
         <td>Table Cell</td>
         <td>Table Cell</td>
         <td>Table Cell</td>
         <td>Table Cell</td>
         <td>Table Cell</td>
         <td>Table Cell</td>
         <td>Table Cell</td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried any thing so far? are you using a database or something to store data, or you are just trying to practice JavaScript or something like that

Answer (score 0):

1. Place an `id` on the cell

```js
<td id="table-cell-1">Table Cell</td>
```

2. Place an `onchange` event handler on your input
3. Update the `innerText` on that cell with `getElementById`

Codepen for updating a value using a single ID and an event handler on an input: https://codepen.io/donald-moore/pen/wvJjmJG

Codepen for your specific use case: https://codepen.io/donald-moore/pen/GRWddKj?editors=1111

Comment: How could I change it so when I enter a name from the modal, when I click submit it updates the change. I am unsure how to make your answer fit with my problem.

Comment: @JustinFulkerson You would just place the same JS logic from the input field's `onchange` event handler into a different type of event handler, such as the submit button's `onclick` handler or a form's `onsubmit` handler — grabbing the value from the input field using another `id`. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp

Comment: @JustinFulkerson Can you create a https://codepen.io for this and I'll do it for you?

Comment: Here is the codepen, I have everything in html though. https://codepen.io/jf451/pen/QWprmXO

Comment: @JustinFulkerson That's fine. Give me just a few minutes.

Comment: Thank you for helping, though when I enter my name for cell in the upper left corner, the whole row goes blank.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233367/discussion-between-justin-fulkerson-and-ihodonald).

Comment: @JustinFulkerson It's kind of hairy because you have to remove the event listeners, but this should work https://codepen.io/donald-moore/pen/GRWddKj